# howto install Mondo an elementary loki (16.04)

Tags: release-loki

I'd like to install Mondo as desaster recovery solution.
I tryed some howto (https://sourceforge.net/p/mondo/mailman/message/35591945/) but no succes. Error was not enough memeory (les 32MB). I think this is more a bug than a real error ,massage :)

Is there any Howto for Mondo for elementary loki?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting that error because you don't have the key to authenticate the repo.

The first command downloads the public key from the source and adds to your apt sources keyring.

```
$ wget -qO - ftp://ftp.mondorescue.org/ubuntu/16.04/mondorescue.pubkey | sudo apt-key add -
$ wget ftp://ftp.mondorescue.org/ubuntu/16.04/mondorescue.sources.list
$ sudo sh -c "cat mondorescue.sources.list >> /etc/apt/sources.list" 
$ sudo apt update 
$ sudo apt install mondo
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to install Mondo Rescue Disaster Recovery Tool on elementary OS 0.4 Loki by doing the following:

`wget ftp://ftp.mondorescue.org/ubuntu/16.04/mondorescue.sources.list
sudo sh -c "cat mondorescue.sources.list >> /etc/apt/sources.list" 
sudo apt update 
sudo apt install mondo`

Comment: Hi Rocco,got a error with source

Comment: W: GPG-Fehler: ftp://ftp.mondorescue.org//ubuntu 16.04 Release: Die folgenden Signaturen konnten nicht überprüft werden, weil ihr öffentlicher Schlüssel nicht verfügbar ist: NO_PUBKEY 6BA8C2D220EBFB0E
W: The repository 'ftp://ftp.mondorescue.org//ubuntu 16.04 Release' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

Comment: None of which is working on Ubuntu Server 16.04.4 LTS... First, can the repo be signed. It's not so hard is it?
Love Mondo, it worked flawl